# title tooltip causes scrolling

Tags: iframe, tooltip, title

I have a multi iframe page.   I produce a chart in JavaScript in each iframe where the title tooltip documents the chart content.   All this works well except when the tooltip shows near the bottom of the iframe.  In Chrome, Edge, and Opera this causes the iframe to scroll vertically.   In FF and IE, no scrolling occurs.   Of course, in IE the tooltip is always above the mouse position.  I would like to prevent this scrolling from happening in Chrome, Edge, and Opera.   I've tried several custom tooltips but nothing has worked yet.   Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
craigt

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```css
.perent {
    position: relative:
}
.tooltip {
    position: absolute:
}
```

to prevent the tooltip from making the page scroll.

Comment: How would I use that?

Comment: the absolute position will prevent the page from scrolling

Comment: Thanks itaysmalia.   I have not been able to get that to work yet, but that scrolling='no', even though deprecated, still works.   It would be nice if they would roll back that deprecation.   For the moment its a temporary fix.